# android - capture of the entire screen programatically

Tags: java, android, screenshot

Is it possible to capture the entire screen from Android application code? I'm developing an application like VNC for Android platform.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is. You just need to create a canvas and assign it a Bitmap, then draw to that canvas instead of the canvas you use in your onDraw method and save the bitmap on the SDcard for example.

Just to renind you that this method will work if you handle the drawing, so you should use a custom home screen for it to capture wether you want. (just get the default android home screen :D).

Comment: I want to capture views from outside of my application.

Comment: Then you should provide a custom home screen which will then capture the screen of all kind of things. But a simple 'capture' all method can only be achieved with a rooted phone, like all the screenshot apps if you do not want to handle the drawing code. If you have root access this will help: http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1473

Answer (score 2):

I think that depends on what you are trying to capture. I'm sure you can use Moss's method to create a screenshot from your own application - that is, something you render yourself.

As I understand it however, capturing from other views, apps, etc. is designed to be impossible for security reasons. This is to avoid apps being able to take screen shots from other apps, which would make it easy to steal sensitive data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have personal experience with it, but this open source project sounds like it might either solve your problem, or provide you clues as to which API to use:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/ashot/

> Screen capturing tool for Android
>   handsets connected via USB to a
>   desktop/laptop. It is great for
>   fullscreen presentations, product
>   demos, automatic screen recording, or
>   just a single screenshot. Without
>   root.

Comment: This tool is based on Android DDMS. There is an API for desktop Java to connect to Android device and take screenshots remotly. I want to screen capture the entire screen (not only my app) from within android application code.